# Casting data in gridview control

Tags: c#, .net

my gridview data source is a list which takes datas from database but my sql command includes inner join and cannot cast the data and the gridview string like this OptikBOLayer.Exams but it can be string

Comment: Sorry, I think that you need to be more explicit about your problem. A single sentence will not do. Please separate what you want to achieve, what you did and what the problem is. Otherwise it's very hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

use cast in c# or convert class